# Does Rig Veda talk about Vishnu using weapons?

Tags: vishnu, rig-veda, weapon

There is very little anthropomorphic description of Vishnu in the Rig Veda. He assists Indra in his battles, but it is not clear if he himself is depicted as fighting.

Comment: What do you mean by the term anthropomorphic? Do you mean to say whether Lord Vishu is described in RigVeda as human as we find about Lord  Indra?

Comment: Yes - as a human as opposed to an abstract principle (the three strides refer to the Sun, without a doubt).  For example, Rudra: He is a fierce looking god, well built and golden in color, with braided hair, "of firm limbs, multiform, strong, tawny, who adorns himself with bright gold decorations. The strength of Godhead never departs from Rudra." Father of Maruts, the Rigvedic hymns describe him eloquently, "Of your pure medicines"